# Dynamically creating a multi-dimensional hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm a PHP developer who's trying to gain some proficiency in Ruby. One of the projects I'm cutting my teeth on now is a source-code auditing tool that scans webapp files for potentially dangerous functions in several web programming languages. When matches are found, the script saves the relevant information in a `poi` (point-of-interest) class for display later on.

An example instance of that class would look something like this (modeled in YAML):

```
poi:
    file_type: "php"
    file: "the-scanned-file.php"
    line_number: 100
    match: "eval()"
    snippet: "echo eval()"
```

On display, I want to organize these points of interest like so:

```
- file_type
-- file
--- match (the searched payload)
```

Thus, before presentation, I'm trying to structure a flat array of `poi` objects into a hash mirroring the structure above. This will allow me to simply iterate over the items in the hash to produce the desired on-screen organization. (Or at least, that's the plan.)

And now, for my question: how do I do that in Ruby?

In PHP, I could do something like this really easily:

```php
<?php

$sorted_pois = array();
foreach($points_of_interest as $point){
    $sorted_pois[$point->file_type][$point->file][$point->match][] = $point;
}

?>
```

I've tried translating that thought from PHP to Ruby like this, but to no avail:

```
sorted_pois = {}
@points_of_interest.each_with_index do |point, index|
    sorted_pois[point.file_type.to_sym][point.file.to_sym][point.match.to_sym].push point
end
```

I've spent a few hours on this, and I'm kind of banging my head against the wall at this point, so presumably I'm way off-base. What's the proper way to handle this in Ruby?

**Update:**

For reference, this is the precise method I have defined:

```
# sort the points of interest into a structured hash
def sort
  sorted_pois = {}
  @points_of_interest.each_with_index do |point, index|
    sorted_pois[point.file_type.to_sym][point.file.to_sym][point.match.to_sym].push point
  end
end
```

This is the error I receive when I run the code:

```
./lib/models/vulnscanner.rb:63:in `sort': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `each_with_index'
    from ./lib/models/vulnscanner.rb:62:in `each'
    from ./lib/models/vulnscanner.rb:62:in `each_with_index'
    from ./lib/models/vulnscanner.rb:62:in `sort'
    from ./webapp-vulnscan:69
```

Line 62 (as you can likely infer) is this line in particular:

```
@points_of_interest.each_with_index do |point, index|
```

As an additional reference, here's what (a snippet of) `@points_of_interest` looks like when converted to YAML:

```
- !ruby/object:PoI 
  file: models/couponkimoffer.php
  file_type: php
  group: :dangerous_functions
  line_number: "472"
  match: `
  snippet: ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
- !ruby/object:PoI 
  file: models/couponkimoffer.php
  file_type: php
  group: :dangerous_functions
  line_number: "818"
  match: `
  snippet: WHERE `company_slug` = '$company_slug'
- !ruby/object:PoI 
  file: models/couponkimoffer.php
  file_type: php
  group: :dangerous_functions
  line_number: "819"
  match: `
  snippet: ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Does it result in errors or is the output not what you expect? Also, providing sample input/output is helpful.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, thanks for taking a look. I just updated the question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

@John's `Enumerable#group_by` suggestion is one good way to solve your needs. Another would be to create an auto-vivifying Hash (like you appear to have in PHP) like so:

```
hash = Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
hash[:a][:b][:c] = 42
p hash
#=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>42}}}
```

Note that this sort of auto-vivification can be 'dangerous' if you access keys that don't exist, as it creates them for you:

```
p hash["does this exist?"]
#=> {}

p hash
#=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>42}}, "does this exist?"=>{}}
```

You can still use the vivifying `default_proc` without hitting this danger if you use `key?` to test for the key first:

```
val = hash["OH NOES"] if hash.key?("OH NOES")
#=> nil

p hash
#=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>42}}, "does this exist?"=>{}}
```

---

FWIW, the error you are getting says, *"Hey, you put `[]` after something that evaluated to `nil`, and `nil` doesn't have a `[]` method."* Specifically, your code...

```
sorted_pois[point.file_type.to_sym]
```

evaluated to `nil` (because the hash did not yet have a value for this key) and then you attempted to ask for

```
nil[point.file.to_sym]
```

Comment: @Phrogz, thanks for taking the time to explain that to me. I'm really starting to like Ruby, but man, it's tricky! This makes it obvious I've got a bit more reading to do :)

Comment: Great answer! Really helped me understand! Thank you for explaining things as well as you did.

Answer (score 9):

You might be interested in [group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

Sample usage:

```
birds = ["Golden Eagle", "Gyrfalcon", "American Robin",
         "Mountain BlueBird", "Mountain-Hawk Eagle"]
grouped_by_first_letter = birds.group_by { |s| s[0] }

# { "G"=>["Golden Eagle", "Gyrfalcon"], "A"=>["American Robin"],
#   "M"=>["Mountain BlueBird", "Mountain-Hawk Eagle"] }
```

Comment: +1 for being right; you may gather more upvotes if you show how it's used beyond linking to the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious problem with the example above is that nested hashes and arrays you try to use don't exist. Try this:

```
sorted_pois = {}
pois.each do |point|
  # sanitize data - convert to hash of symbolized keys and values
  poi = Hash[ %w{file_type file match}.map do |key| 
    [key.to_sym, point.send(key).to_sym]
  end ]

  # create nested hash/array if it doesn't already exist
  sorted_pois[ poi[:file_type] ] ||= {}
  sorted_pois[ poi[:file_type] ][ poi[:file] ] ||= {}
  sorted_pois[ poi[:file_type] ][ poi[:file] ][ poi[:match] ] ||= []

  sorted_pois[ poi[:file_type] ][ poi[:file] ][ poi[:match] ] << point
end
```

Comment: This is the 'safer' way to manually create the nestings; see my answer for a less-safe-but-more-convenient way.