# Hash of Hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a problem to solve, There is a simple supermarket program where all items are sorted and stored in a hash(key: Product ID) that has values such as price, manufacturer, expiry etc.
For a purpose, i need to group items according to price.
I need to create a hash (keyed: price) containing another hash (keyed: Product ID).

Code goes like this:

```
new_Hash = Hash.new(Hash.new)
items = Hash.new
SuperMarket_hash.each { |Product_ID, info | new_Hash[info.PRICE].items[Product_ID] }
```

I am getting error for this code. (items : NillClass no method error)

Comment: [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) is what you're looking for. Something like `SuperMarket_hash.group_by { |Product_ID, info| info.PRICE }`, but your question is hard to understand, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a vivified hash as shown in "[Dynamically creating a multi-dimensional hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253105/dynamically-creating-a-multi-dimensional-hash-in-ruby/10253359#10253359)"

Or use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).