# Clean way to create a hash with 3 levels of nesting which creates levels if they don't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, activesupport

This is what I do now

```
h = Hash.new { |h1, k1| h1[k1] = Hash.new { |h2, k2| h2[k2] = {} } }
```

Although it works, it looks kind of ambiguous. Maybe there is a better way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
```

Then you can assign in anyway you like,

```
h[:a][:b][:c][:d] = 3
```

Reference: [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253105/dynamically-creating-a-multi-dimensional-hash-in-ruby/10253359#10253359)

Answer (score 1):

You can create one recursively like this.

```
def create n
  return {} if n == 0
  Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = create(n - 1)}
end

h  = create 3
h[1][1][1] = 2
p h[1][1][1]       # => 2
p h[2][1][2]       # => {}
h[2][1][2] = 3
p h                # => {1=>{1=>{1=>2}}, 2=>{1=>{2=>3}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. You can just classify it:

```
class NestedHash < Hash

  def initialize(depth)
    self.default_proc = Proc.new {|h,k| h[k] = NestedHash.new(depth-1)} if depth && depth > 1
  end

end

h = NestedHash.new(3)
```