# Ruby hashes with a primary and secondary key

Tags: ruby, arrays, perl, hash

The data I am reading in from a RabbitMQ queue has the following values: `epoch, id, wait, length, max`. I want to put this information into a hash of hashes. In Perl I would have done it like this:

```
%hash = ( $spid => { $epoch => { 'wait' => $wait, 'length' => $length, 'max' => $max } } );
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253105/dynamically-creating-a-multi-dimensional-hash-in-ruby/10253359) seemed close, but I either don't understand the replies or it isn't what I am looking for. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated in learning how to do this in Ruby.

Comment: Not very sure, what you want. What's your input data ? how does it look like?

Comment: This depends on how the data your given looks. Can you provide what you get?

Comment: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_hashes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No big difference:

```
epoch, id, wait, length, max = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
hash = {id => {epoch => {'wait' => wait, 'length' => length, 'max' => max}}}
p hash                 # => {2=>{1=>{"wait"=>3, "length"=>4, "max"=>5}}}
puts hash[2][1]["max"] # => 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Hash of hashes:

```
mainHash = {}
h1 = { 'test' => 1, 'test2' => 2}
h2 = { 'asdf' => 3 }
mainHash[:h1] = h1
mainHash[:h2] = h2
```

To access 'asdf' value:

```
mainHash[:h2]['asdf']
```

How you get the data to put in the hashes is up to the data.