# Ruby: Unexpected result from Hash.keys in multi-dimensional hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following small sequence, which makes no sense to me:

```
irb(main):001:0> h = {}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> h.default = {}
=> {}
irb(main):003:0> h["foo"]["bar"] = 6
=> 6
irb(main):004:0> h.length
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> h.keys
=> []
irb(main):006:0> h["foo"]
=> {"bar"=>6}
```

How is is that step 5 returns an empty list of keys, and step 4 indicates the length of `h` is `0`, yet I can see in step 6 that `"foo"` is a valid key and has an associated value. I would expect `keys` to return `["foo"]`, and `length` to return `1`.

What am I misunderstanding? Note this is Ruby 1.9.3p0

Also note this works correctly:

```
irb(main):001:0> h = {}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> h["foo"] = {}
=> {}
irb(main):003:0> h["foo"]["bar"] = 6
=> 6
irb(main):004:0> h.length
=> 1
irb(main):005:0> h.keys
=> ["foo"]
irb(main):006:0> h["foo"]
=> {"bar"=>6}
```

The only difference is the use of Hash.default to set the default value and skip the explicit initialization of `h["foo"]`. Is this a bug?

Comment: Here's something else for you to mull over: `h[:narf]` => `{"bar" => 6}`. That's a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set the default value that will be returned if no value is found. This doesn't change the fact that there is no value assigned to `h["foo"]`. `{"bar"=>6}` will be the value for any key which is not found.

```
h = {}
h.default = {}      # => {}
h["foo"]["bar"] = 6 # => 6
h["foo"]            # => {"bar"=>6}
h["baz"]            # => {"bar"=>6}
```

If you wanted a hash which returns and sets values of missing keys to empty hashes, you have to do:

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {} }
h["foo"]["bar"] = 6  # => 6
h                    # => {:foo=>{:bar=>6}}
```

Comment: Consider replacing the third line with `g=h["foo"] #=> {}; g.object_id #=> 70256236167680; g["bar"]=6  #=> 6; h["foo"].object_id #=> 70256236167680`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, which third line?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, they are about the same size. xd

Comment: Using `h.default = {}` means all elements of the hash would point to the same object in memory. `h["foo"]["bar"].object_id #=> 13` and `h["baz"]['bar'].object_id #=> 13`. That's NOT how you want a hash to behave.

Comment: @theTinMan, I know, it was a copy-paste from OP's question. This is what I did to show that if he accesses another key, he will get the same hash. This was not my recommendation, but the explanation of the problem. The actual solution is the second part of the answer, which is to use the hash constructor with block.

Comment: @theTinMan, could you read the question and answer once more and reconsider?

Comment: Your "real answer" is only delaying the inevitable. The problem is that the default for dynamically creating hashes has to take into account how deeply that hash could nest.

Comment: @theTinMan, no it isn't. There is no infinite nesting here. There is only one level of nesting. Did you try my solution in the console? The constructor block is being executed each time a new key is being accessed. There wont be value sharing between different keys.

Comment: I have used this answer's suggested solution and it neatly solved my stated problem. It explained what was wrong with my approach, pointed me to a useful constructor pattern for Hash which can be used to initialize new keys, and gave me a solution for my specific problem. Thanks for an answer which is clear, concise, and illuminating!

Answer (score 2):

The line `h.default = {}` means that the default value that is returned in case the key is missing is `{}`. Moreover, it is this particular hash instance that will be returned.

The line `h["foo"]["bar"] = 6` looks for the key `foo` and when it can't find it, it fetches the default value `{}` and inserts into it the key `bar` and value `6`. The hash is still empty after this.

This is the reason why you see these results.

You may use [default_proc](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D) to also set the key.

Answer (score 0):

Meditate on this:

```
h={} #=> {}
h['foo'] #=> nil
```

Because `['foo']` doesn't exist trying to access it results in a nil. That means that trying to access a sub-hash of `'foo'` would fail:

```
h['foo']['bar']

NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

That'd be the equivalent of using:

```
nil['bar']

NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

We can fix this by defining what `h['foo']` is:

```
h['foo'] = {} #=> {}
```

It's defined, so when we request its value we get an empty hash:

```
h['foo'] #=> {}
```

And now `h['foo']['bar']` will return something expected, a nil:

```
h['foo']['bar'] # => nil
```

And, at that point an assignment to `h['foo']['bar']` will make sense:

```
h['foo']['bar'] = 6
```

And looking at `h` shows we've got a hash of hashes:

```
h # => {"foo"=>{"bar"=>6}}
```

Using `h.default = {}` is an attempt to work around the problem of `h['foo']` returning nil:

```
h = {}
h.default = {}
h # => {}
h['foo'] # => {}
```

And, yes, it does that, but it also introduces a MAJOR problem. We expect hashes to return the value of the key consistently, but `h.default = {}` has set up a problem. Normally we want a hash to behave like this:

```
h = {}
h # => {}
h['foo'] = {}
h['bar'] = {}
h # => {"foo"=>{}, "bar"=>{}}
h['foo']['baz'] = 1
h['bar']['baz'] = 2
h # => {"foo"=>{"baz"=>1}, "bar"=>{"baz"=>2}}
h['foo'].object_id # => 70179045516300
h['bar'].object_id # => 70179045516280
h['foo']['baz'].object_id # => 3
h['bar']['baz'].object_id # => 5
```

Using `h.default = {}` breaks that. We knew `h['foo']` existed and we'd expect that `h['bar']` would be non-existent or point to a different key/value pair in memory, but it won't:

```
h = {}
h.default = {}
h # => {}
h['foo']['baz'] = 1
h['bar']['baz'] = 2
h # => {}
h['foo'].object_id # => 70142994238340
h['bar'].object_id # => 70142994238340
h['foo']['baz'] # => 2
h['bar']['baz'] # => 2
h['foo']['baz'].object_id # => 5
h['bar']['baz'].object_id # => 5
```

You *really* don't want that to happen as it's totally alien and unexpected behavior, which would make your code break in weird and wonderful ways, plus make you hated by anyone else maintaining/debugging your code.

The whole problem is the use of `h.default = {}` because it doesn't mean "always use a new hash" it means "always use this hash".

Instead, something like this would work and fix the problem:

```
h = Hash.new{ |hash,key| hash[key] = Hash.new(&hash.default_proc) }

h['foo']['baz'] = 1
h['bar']['baz'] = 2
h # => {"foo"=>{"baz"=>1}, "bar"=>{"baz"=>2}}
h['foo'].object_id # => 70109399098340
h['bar'].object_id # => 70109399098320
h['foo']['baz'] # => 1
h['bar']['baz'] # => 2
h['foo']['baz'].object_id # => 3
h['bar']['baz'].object_id # => 5
```

At this point, the hash should behave as expected and nobody would want to hunt you down. There are some gotchas to this solution but it's a better building block. See "[Dynamically creating a multi-dimensional hash in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10253105/128421)" for more information.